# static and anonymous block of code what are they what is the difference

Tags: apex

I have no idea why I can't find the information related to this topic it seems like I was cursed, please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Static code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm) is code run the first time a class is referenced/loaded in memory. For example:

```
 public class A {
   public static Boolean B;
   static {
     B = true;
   }
 }
```

If you then run the following code elsewhere:

```
if(A.B) {
  System.debug('B was true!');
}
```

Then the result will be true, even though it was not initialized directly.

Anonymous blocks, on the other hand, is simply any code run by [`executeAnonymous()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm&type=5), an API call that allows you to run arbitrary Apex code, and requires the Author Apex permission to use. You can call this API method a number of ways, including the Developer Console, VS Code's Salesforce DX bundle, or with your own custom code that can call the API.

Static blocks are used to initialize a class' static data. They cannot contain classes, methods, or other class-level properties, as they are otherwise just "normal" methods that happen to not have a name or parameters. However, they are called automatically, only once, for each transaction. You cannot manually call them.

Anonymous blocks are blocks executed on the fly, without deploying Apex to the org. They can contain methods, classes, and other class-level features (with some limitations). They are typically used to perform one-off bits of code, such as scheduling a class, kicking off a batch process, etc, without having that specific code deployed beforehand.